# Facebook pixel events AddToCart and Purchase not coming up in facebook analytics

Tags: facebook, facebook-analytics

I have a peculiar problem with facebook pixel tracking where PageView events are working fine but AddToCart and Purchase events are tracked in FB but not displayed in the analytics screen.

[image: Pixel helper for add to cart]
[image: Pixel helper for Purchase]

Now in the FB Events manager, I can see the events as expected:

[image: FB Events manager]

And the same pixel in FB analytics:
[image]

Note, there are different FB pixel IDs firing on the site, I am using the trackSingle approach, as described by FB.

Weird thing is that another FB pixel tracks all events fine, the only difference being. The other pixel that works is paired with FB product feed and sends content params. (Obviously, both pixels cannot be paired with a product catalogue).

If anyone from FB reading this, the pixel ID in question is: 444449759371803

Comment: What resolved the issues was creating a new pixel - which is tracking fine. I even experimented with putting the old pixel back in (same issue) and reverting back to the new pixel (tracking fine).

Comment: so you created a new fb pixel within your ads manager, and deployed that on site, and that fixed the issue? i have all sorts of discrepancies across multiple ad accounts when comparing them in fb analytics. most of the fb ad account managers seem to know much about it.